# Presta shop - smarty cache problem

Tags: caching, smarty, prestashop

The question is that has anyone setup the presta shop with cache true and compile false smarty options?

If this options are enabled nothing is working as it schould the smarty ->assing can be done only once if you put other value to a placeholder only the first will be active.

The adding to cart or deleteing is not working.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

That just normal if you ready Smarty doc : http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/caching cache option will cache the first smarty->display rendering to use this result during the next 3600 seconds.